# Worded trig question

Tags: trigonometry

From the top of a vertical cliff 125m high, the angle of depression to the top of a ship is 3.5°. If the ship is 1800m from the base of the cliff, determine the height of the ship above the water.

I have never been good at worded questions and would appreciate the help

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Draw out a picture of the problem and link it, for a start.

Comment: That's also a problem, I'm not sure how to draw it out.

Comment: The only "jargon" I see that anyone might have trouble interpreting is angle of depression. This can easily be looked up, but to save you the trouble, it's the angle made by the line of sight (viewing)  to the horizontal. So you're observing from the top of the cliff and looking slightly downward at the top of a distant ship. If you take a laser pointer and align the beam exactly with your line of vision, that line will make an angle of 3.5 degrees with the horizontal. Does that help? The rest of it is just basic English interpretation.